# Using room persistence when trying to fetch items or insert returns null database

Tags: android

Working with room persistence, when trying to get the database to insert or make select in the items, the error appears:

> AppDataBase.getMovieDao()' on a null object reference

The classes related to the process are as follows:

AppDataBase class:

```
@Database(entities = {Movies.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDataBase extends RoomDatabase {

    public static final String DB_NAME = "Movies";
    private static AppDataBase INSTANCE;

    public static AppDataBase getDataBase(Context context){
        if (INSTANCE == null){
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),AppDataBase.class,DB_NAME).build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public abstract MovieDao getMovieDao();
}
```

Dao Class:

```
@Dao
public interface MovieDao {

    @Insert
    void insertAll(Movies movies);

    @Update
    void updateAll(Movies... notes);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM moviestb")
    List<Movies> getAll();

    @Delete
    void deleteAll(Movies... notes);

}
```

Entity class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "moviestb")
public class Movies {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "idmovie")
    private long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "titlemovie")
    private String titlemovie;
........
}
```

Searching for the registrations:

```
public void loadFromDB(){
    db.getDataBase(view.getContext());
    if(db.getMovieDao().getAll().size() > 0){
        adapter.setResults(db.getMovieDao().getAll());
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Não há filmes cadastrados",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        view.getActivity().finish();
    }
}
```

Insert:

```
public View.OnClickListener onSaveClick(final String plot, final String diretor, final String autor,
                                            final String nome, final String tipo, final String ano, final String ator, final String imdb) {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View itemView) {
                db.getDataBase(view.getContext());
                Movies movies = new Movies(nome,plot,imdb,"",ator,ano,tipo,diretor,autor);
                new InsertAsyncTask(db).execute(movies);

            }
        };
    }

    private class InsertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Movies,Void,Void>{
        private AppDataBase db;
        public InsertAsyncTask(AppDataBase appDataBase) {
            db = appDataBase;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Movies... params) {
            db.getMovieDao().insertAll(params[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Searching all:

```
public void loadFromDB(){
    db.getDataBase(view.getContext());
    if(db.getMovieDao().getAll().size() > 0){
        adapter.setResults(db.getMovieDao().getAll());
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Não há filmes cadastrados",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        view.getActivity().finish();
    }
}
```

The crash occurs while fetching the database, what am I doing wrong? thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db` is `null`, apparently. Your question does not show where you ever assign it a value.

Please note that `getDataBase()` is a `static` method. Perhaps you should have a `db=AppDataBase.getDataBase()` statement somewhere.

Comment: Yep, my db is null. I get de value on loadfromdb, for example.

Comment: @HenriqueMendes: Please understand that all your `db.getDataBase(view.getContext());` calls are useless. First, `db` is `null`, and so those should crash. Second, you ignore the return value, which is the point of calling that method.